# How to constraint at most one element of variable vector could be non-zero in mosek?

Tags: optimization, convex, mosek

I'm solving a problem like this:

```
    Variable X = {x0, x1}

    maximize AX + B

    subject to 0 <= x0 <= c0,
               0 <= x1 <= c1,
               x0 * x1 <= 0
```

It's to say that, I want to get a solution of X with at most one non-zero element.

I'm not sure if problems like this could be solved with mosek.
Could someone give me some help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeap you can solve this, it better to try yourself, so that we can help

Comment: Duplicated at https://groups.google.com/g/mosek/c/-TWVvglwqB8

Comment: Yep, I've seen your reply. I'll try it. Thanks a lot! @ErlingMOSEK